# How to get VScode recognize d.ts files without referencing them directly

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a project created with [create-react-app-ts](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript)

I also have a set of `d.ts` files that are generated interfaces from JSON-schema. They define some interfaces for a remote API.

I would like these `d.ts` file to be "globally" available throughout the project, without the need to directly reference them by file name. Somewhat similar to how `Promise<T>` definition is available globally.

I've tried modifying `tsconfig`, added `path/to/**/*.dts` to `include`, as well as in `files`. I also tried adding path to `"typeRoots"` under `compilerOptopns`.

This makes the project compile, but VSCode provides no IntelliSense to these interfaces, and underlines them as unknown.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've hit this too. By default TS should pick up any file *.d.ts but it doesn't

Comment: @sidonaldson yes you need to add something like `"types": "index.d.ts"` to your `package.json`

Comment: I have the same issue where ts compiles with no issue, but VSCode does not provide intellisense. One 'solution' I've found is vscode does give intellisense if you have the `.d.ts` file open in another tab. This is not satisfactory though (I don't want to keep multiple definition files open just to write code with intellisense).

Answer (score 7):

Based on [tsconfig compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), you should use option `typeRoots`. [This section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) of documentation describes the difference between `@types`, `typeRoots` and `types`.

For your specific case this `tsconfig.json` file should do the trick:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots" : ["./type-definitions-folder"]
    }
}
```

If you are also using type definitions from npm you should also add `./node_modules/@types`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types", "./type-definitions-folder"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I should update my post to mention that I tried that option too, like I say project builds, so not a `tsc` problem, but VSCode intellisense still *doesn't work*

Comment: That's strange.  If you still need help, the fastest way to find the problem is probably for you to publish a repository that reproduces the problem (after removing any confidential information).

Comment: Can you explain the reference to "type-definitions-folder"?  Does this just mean the root directory e.g., where the tsconfig.json is located?  Or wherever your global.d.ts file is located?

Comment: Open the VS command input (cmd+shift+p in mac) and type "typescript: restart ts server" and choose the option from the list. This will restart VS typescript engine, detecting the new configuration.

Answer (score 3):

If TypeScript compiles without errors, but VSCode still can't recognize global types and add proper intellisense, then **it's likely that you have a project with too many files and you are not being specific enough about the files you want TypeScript to check.**

To add intellisense to global types, VSCode iterates over all files available, since you did not specify which ones to check, or was too broad about it. With too many files, VSCode stops looking around.

Using `typeRoots` to declare your global types folder/files should be enough for VSCode to spot what files it should look for. **If it doesn't happen, consider specifying all the paths you expect intellisense to work in the `include` field, or remove all the files you don't want in the `exclude` field.** VSCode should follow and add intellisense to the missing files.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "path/to/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
      // Add all paths you want intellisense to work
      "path/to/where/you/expect/intellisense/to/work",
      "path/to/another/file/or/folder"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not help me at all.

Comment: thanks，Your method is useful, but there are some errors in the writing, you need to write the following
```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["./typings"]
    },
    "include": ["./src/*", "./typings/*"]
}
```

Comment: I thought it was implicit but you are right: explicit > implicit. Thanks!